# CodeIgniter PHPWord template not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword

I'm facing trouble when using PHPWord with CodeIgniter in loadTemplate always return error "Template Not Found".

I'm using phpword in third party and create Word.php class in library to call it.

My CodeIgniter not a pure one. It already injected like some homemade cms from previous programmer.

My Question is how to I know where is the path of loadTemplate?
Any info needed you can ask me I will provide for you

Thanks,
Hendra

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your scenario, but in any case there is no magic in how the path of loadTemplate works - it works exactly the same as you would access any file with php, i.e. either you place your template file under the phpunit library and use a relative path or you place your file somewhere else and use a full path (or some alias if you have some defined in your server (apache/nginx/..) configuration).